# Which to choose Workflow Or Process Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow

We are often asked in an interview that which one you will choose Process builder or  Workflow for update the record or create the record so here I stuck with the answer with suitable reason. Can anyone please explain with an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would answer this kind of question, that I will choose Record-Triggered Flow :)

Workflows and Processes are soon going to be retired. Source [Salesforce to Retire Workflow Rules and Process Builder](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-to-retire-workflow-rules-and-process-builder/)

> So, the writing has been on the wall for some time, but during
> Dreamforce ‘21, the Product Manager responsible for the retirement,
> Patrick Stokes, delivered more detail about what to expect.
>
> Patrick explained that there will be a formal end-of-life roadmap,
> governed by an end-of-life council, and they have several stages of
> retirement planned (Safe Harbor):
>
> Spring ‘22 release: launch migration tool for Workflow Rules
>
> Summer ‘22 release: launch migration tool for Process Builder
>
> Winter ‘23> release: you will no longer be able to create new Process Builders or
> Workflow Rules

as for now, **Winter '22** In general, in salesforce,  there are 3 main declarative tools that allow triggering some automation per some condition:

- Workflow Rule
- Process Builder
- Record-Triggered Flow

Each of them has its specification and limitations.

Per my personal view, the following are the key points:

*Workflow*

This is the oldest tool among listed. Triggered by record insert/update. Can be used for some simple update of the field which is triggered this action or its parent. Can't update child records. Can create only Task records.

*Process Builder*

Was introduced as an alternative for workflow, when you need to perform more complex actions based on more complex logic. Triggered on record insert/update, publishing platform event, or triggered by another process. Good support for branching entry condition, which allows implementing different behavior based on different conditions. Can update any related record, can create records, can call apex. Can't delete records.

*Record-Triggered Flow (Flow Builder)*

The newest salesforce declarative tool, which is very flexible and it is possible to do almost everything in it. In addition to what can be done by process builder, the flow has the following additional actions: can delete record, can update any record (not related at all), can be triggered, when the record is deleted, supports before record action (like before insert in the apex trigger), which allows to set field value and commit it to DB without the DML.

---

To view the entire picture and possibilities of mentioned declarative automation tools take a look at [Which Automation Tool Do I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.process_which_tool.htm&type=5)

Comment: Note that Salesforce recently announced the up-coming retirement of workflows and process builders, both being replaced by flows. IIRC this was for late next year.